# Get X value graph for a certain Y value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am analyzing qPCR data and I have a Y-value threshold for which I want to get the corresponding X value.
This is my code for the plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=qPCR_amplification_plot_data_IFI6, aes(x=`Cycle`, y=`dRn...3`))+
  geom_line(data=qPCR_amplification_plot_data_IFI6, aes(x=`Cycle`, y=`dRn...5`))+
  geom_point()+
  labs(y = "ΔRn", title = "Amplification plot", x= "Cycle")+
  scale_y_continuous(trans='log10', limits = c(0.001,10))+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.04)
```

I know how to get Y value for a certain X value:

```
Intersect <- approxfun(qPCR_amplification_plot_data_IFI6$Cycle, qPCR_amplification_plot_data_IFI6$dRn...3)
Intersect(X)
```

But I would like to get the X value of the Y threshold (for example 0.4). How can I do that?

[qPCR amplification plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYvX4.png)

Comment: Just an idea. Switch x and y. `Intersect_Y <- approxfun(qPCR_amplification_plot_data_IFI6$dRn...3, qPCR_amplification_plot_data_IFI6$Cycle)` should give you the inverse if that is well defined.

Comment: @stefan Thanks for your answer. This did the trick! I feel kind of stupid for not thinking of it myself (but I am very grateful).

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this using a combination of `which()` and `near()` (from `dplyr`).  `which()` can evaluate "which part of this is TRUE", effectively:

```
x <- 1:100

> which(x==4)
[1] 4
```

`near()` can be used as a logical expression of "kind of close to" - so good for approximations:

```
4 == 4.01
[1] FALSE

near(4, 4.01, tol=0.01)
[1] TRUE

near(4, 4.01, tol=0.001)
[1] FALSE
```

So you can use those two together to basically answer the question: "Which X value in my vector `Intersect` is close to Y?"

```
which(near(Intersect, Y, tol = your.tolerance))
```

*By the way, I am assuming that `Intersect(X)` in your code is a typo and you have a vector `Intersect[X]`*